# Net Core NLog.Web "aspnet-user-identity" is empty?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

I was using "NLog.Extensions.Logging" for logging and need to log user identity and found that it is possible with "NLog.Web.AspNetCore". "nlog.config" file is configured to log the "aspnet-user-identity". However, when I look at logs, user identity part is always empty string, the other columns are look pretty good. Am I missing something?

A part of my configuration file is here:

```xml
<extensions>
  <assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
</extensions>

<parameter name="@identity" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"/>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" appendTo="database"/>
```

And an insert command insert a log to db with "@identity" parameter, but it is always empty like I said.

Comment: Had you called `app.AddNLogWeb();` in startup.cs? See https://github.com/NLog/NLog.web

Comment: Yes I've called the method @Julian, forgot to add it to my question.

Comment: It's using `context.User.Identity.Name`, where `context` is `GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()`. Could you check if that still works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the issue,

There was an breaking change, The IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default anymore. ([See announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190))

So add in your startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
{
    //call this in case you need aspnet-user-authtype/aspnet-user-identity
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Julian ! That was the problem :)

Comment: I needed to use `services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` because `IHttpContextAccessor` was ambigious between NLog.Web and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http. But it did solve it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer didn't worked for my case (using JwtSecurityToken on ASP.NET Core 3.1), 
Later realized that I just forgot to add the ClaimTypes.Name on my JwtSecurityToken Claims.

Now its working and no need to register IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: Thank you. I use regular login on part of the app, and those accounts were displayed with layout="${aspnet-user-identity}", without regisering the IHttpContextAccessor.
But it was not working for the API that works with JwtSecurityTokens. Registering the claim type 
userClaims.Add( new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while searching for "asp.net core nlog username". Eventually I found the solution and I am logging it here for posterity.

**Problem**

How do I include the currently logged in user's username in my NLog log messages?

**Solution**

I am using NLog inside of my ASP.NET Core web app. I tried using the `${aspnet-user-identity}` layout renderer, but determined that the value was empty because we were using custom authentication.

After doing some digging, I figured out that I could access values stored as a ASP.NET Session variable from NLog. So, after I authenticated the user, I stuffed their username into a session variable and voila!

Here is the code I call after authenticating the user:

```cs
// Store username in session so we can access it from NLog logs.
httpContext.Session.SetString("NlogUser", contact.Username);
```

Here is what the layout renderer line in the nlog.config looks like

```xml
<parameter name="@identity" layout="${aspnet-session:variable=NlogUser}"/>
```

Here is the corresponding NLog documenation for the [AspNetSession layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetSession-layout-renderer).

Answer (score 0):

If you recently upgraded ASP.NET Core you may have to configure NLog differently in program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                    {
                        //logging.AddNLog(); //<--- Can remove (NLog.Extensions.Logging)
                    })
                    ;
            })
            .UseNLog(); // <--- Call UseNLog off of IHostBuilder (NLog.Web)
}
```

see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3