# NLog - Render username on the current request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-identity, nlog

I setting up the NLog logging provider according to [this](https://blog.elmah.io/nlog-tutorial-the-essential-guide-for-logging-from-csharp/) documentation. I am using AspNetCore.Identity for authentication/authorization and I found out that I can log as well the requester's username by including ${aspnet-user-identity} in the layout renderer.

The problem is, the username does not show up:

```
2020-06-12 18:08:04.4495|ERROR|API.Controllers.ReportController|Hi |url: https://localhost/api/v1/reports/6|action: GetReport|user:
```

What I want is:

```
2020-06-12 18:08:04.4495|ERROR|API.Controllers.ReportController|Hi |url: https://localhost/api/v1/reports/6|action: GetReport|user: example@example.com
```

Here are my configurations:

***nlog.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile=".\SystemLogs\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target name="500s" xsi:type="File" fileName=".\SystemLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target name="catch-exception" xsi:type="File" fileName=".\ErrorLogs\${shortdate}\handled-errors-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|user: ${aspnet-user-identity}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="catch-exception" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

***Program.cs - CreateWebHostBuilder Method***

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             //attach additional JSON files
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
             {
                 config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot", "Configurations", "EventTypes.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                 config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot", "Notifications", "NotificationLangTemplates.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
             })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
            })
            .UseNLog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

***Sample Controller*** - When I try to log anything

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class UserReportController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UserReportController> logger;

        public UserReportController(ILogger<UserReportController> logger)
        {            
            this.logger = logger;
        }


        [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.UserReports.Get)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(int reportId)
        {          
            logger.LogError("Log error");
            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this might help you. looks like a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715331/net-core-nlog-web-aspnet-user-identity-is-empty